# Please explain the output , where the C character pointer was assigned to new memory without Malloc call

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  char *a = "Hello";
  a = "Hello_World";
  printf ("%s", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Now this program returned corrected and printed “Hello_World”.

But I remember reading that for changing a once initialised string pointer , I must use malloc to allocate memory and then input the new value of the string .

Please explain? Especially where is the memory allocated for the new changed value of the string , and what about the old memory.

Comment: Both `"Hello"` and `"Hello_World"` are *String Literals* which are technically character arrays that reside in read-only memory (with few exceptions). Therefore each array has its own address and on access, the array is converted to a pointer to its first element. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) Since both arrays are converted to a pointer on access (subject to the exceptions not relevant here), they can be assigned to the pointer `a`, where `a` then holds that address as its value.

Comment: Similar to `int n = 5; n = 9; printf ("%d\n", n);` except `n` holds an immediate value while `a` holds the address for where a character is located in memory somewhere else.

Comment: But we are usually not encouraged to do such operations on strings , why is that ? Usually when we want dynamic strings we use malloc

Comment: Also , now in a function if we use a local variable say n=10 then when we leave the scope of the function , that variable’s memory gets freed . Is it the same with string literals ?

Comment: You are not assigning the String, you are assigning an Address. Which is the type of variable a pointer holds. You can't do `char b[10];` and then `b = "Hello";` because arrays are not lvalues and cannot be assigned (only initialized). That is a separate case. Here it would be similar to `int i = 5; int j = 20; int *c = &i;` the `c = &j;` You are just assigning a different address to the pointer. That's all `a` is -- a pointer, it can hold and address.

Comment: You are correct about the local variable in a function because once the function returns, the memory holding the local variables is destroyed (actually released for re-use), so an assignment of a local variable to a function isn't valid once the function returns.

Comment: Understood , so just like local pointers to local variables inside a function , will all the memory of the string literals be freed when we leave the function scope ?

Comment: String literals are static arrays and are good for the life of the program. You do not have to worry about that memory being freed - those are just normal arrays held in a different section that go away all by themselves when the program ends. The only storage you have to worry about freeing is *Allocated Storage* reserved by `mailloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. All other memory simply goes out of scope when the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use gcc -S to see generated assembler.

You well see something like this

```
.LC0:
   .string "Hello"
.LC1:
   .string "Hello_World"
```

It was allocated in .data section as constants.
Then it wil be used like this

```
    movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
    movq    $.LC1, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
```